# Match all img tags with certain src value

Tags: regex

I have a html like this:

```
<script>
    $(“table:first”).after(“<a href=\“https://example.com/test123/\” 
    style=\“display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin- 
    bottom: 116px;\“><img 
    src=\“https://example.com/images/banners/image.png\” alt=\“Example\” 
    width=\“88px\”  style=\“display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; \“></a>“);
</script>

<img src="https://example.com/images/banners/image1.png" alt="image">
```

I need search all img tags with url:
`https://example.com/images/banners/image1.png` and `https://example.com/images/banners/image.png`. I need return true only if I matched one of these url. How I can do it? My pattern:

```
`<img.+?src=[\"']((?:https://example.com/images/banners/image1.png?|www).*)[\"'].*?>`
```

But I get errors:

```
 https://regexr.com/4capb
```

Comment: Just escape the forward slashes: [see my fix](https://regexr.com/4caph).

Comment: @TimKlein not working with `image.png`. You can see img in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the solidus (/) characters, this have a special meaning in regex.

So:

```
 <img.+?src=[\"']((?:https:\/\/example.com\/images\/banners\/image1.png?|www).*)[\"'].*?>
```

Comment: It does work.  You have a weird garbage character there that looks like a dot as the first element of the regex.  Delete it; it's not in my answer.